# exe started with CreateProcessAsUser randomly crashes on start

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services, createprocessasuser

Here is the situation : I have a C# .NET Windows service (run as localsystem) that starts a satellite C# .NET executable (windowless WinForms) under the current logged in user account, using [CreateProcessAsUser](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682429%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Sometimes it works, sometimes... it doesn't. I can see the exe showing up in the tasks manager for just a second, and disappearing. The main method of the exe does not get hit, so I think the problem comes from CreateProcessAsUser.

The event viewer shows an Application Error with code 0xc06d007e, which is of no help. There is also a Windows Error Reporting that says to look at dump files, but those are missing from the path being given.

I have no idea how to debug that. If at least I could see a real error.

It's completely random.

EDIT:

Here is some code as asked.

```
public static uint? LaunchAsCurrentUser(string cmdLine)
{
    IntPtr token = GetCurrentUserToken();

    if (token == IntPtr.Zero)
        return null;

    IntPtr envBlock = GetEnvironmentBlock(token);
    uint? processId = LaunchProcessAsUser(cmdLine, token, envBlock);
    if (envBlock != IntPtr.Zero)
        DestroyEnvironmentBlock(envBlock);

    CloseHandle(token);
    return processId;
}

private static uint LaunchProcessAsUser(string cmdLine, IntPtr token, IntPtr envBlock)
{
    PROCESS_INFORMATION processInformation = new PROCESS_INFORMATION();
    SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES saProcess = new SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES();
    SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES saThread = new SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES();
    saProcess.nLength = (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(saProcess);
    saThread.nLength = (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(saThread);

    STARTUPINFO si = new STARTUPINFO();
    si.cb = (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(si);

    //if this member is NULL, the new process inherits the desktop
    //and window station of its parent process. If this member is
    //an empty string, the process does not inherit the desktop and
    //window station of its parent process; instead, the system
    //determines if a new desktop and window station need to be created.
    //If the impersonated user already has a desktop, the system uses the
    //existing desktop.

    si.lpDesktop = string.Empty; //Modify as needed
    si.dwFlags = STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW | STARTF_FORCEONFEEDBACK;
    si.wShowWindow = SW_SHOW;
    //Set other si properties as required.

    bool result = CreateProcessAsUser(
        token,
        null,
        cmdLine,
        ref saProcess,
        ref saThread,
        false,
        CREATE_UNICODE_ENVIRONMENT,
        envBlock,
        null,
        ref si,
        out processInformation);

    if (!result)
    {
        int error = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
        string message = String.Format("CreateProcessAsUser Error: {0}", error);
        throw new ApplicationException(message);
    }

    return processInformation.dwProcessId;
}

private static IntPtr GetEnvironmentBlock(IntPtr token)
{
    IntPtr envBlock = IntPtr.Zero;
    bool retVal = CreateEnvironmentBlock(ref envBlock, token, false);
    if (retVal == false)
    {
        // Environment Block, things like common paths to My Documents etc.
        // Will not be created if "false"
        // It should not adversley affect CreateProcessAsUser.

        string message = String.Format("CreateEnvironmentBlock Error: {0}", Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
        throw new ApplicationException(message);

    }

    return envBlock;
}

private static IntPtr GetCurrentUserToken()
{
    IntPtr currentToken = IntPtr.Zero;
    IntPtr primaryToken = IntPtr.Zero;
    IntPtr WTS_CURRENT_SERVER_HANDLE = IntPtr.Zero;

    int dwSessionId = 0;
    IntPtr hUserToken = IntPtr.Zero;
    IntPtr hTokenDup = IntPtr.Zero;

    IntPtr pSessionInfo = IntPtr.Zero;
    int dwCount = 0;

    WTSEnumerateSessions(WTS_CURRENT_SERVER_HANDLE, 0, 1, ref pSessionInfo, ref dwCount);

    Int32 dataSize = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(WTS_SESSION_INFO));

    Int64 current = (long)pSessionInfo;
    for (int i = 0; i < dwCount; i++)
    {
        WTS_SESSION_INFO si =
            (WTS_SESSION_INFO)Marshal.PtrToStructure((IntPtr)current, typeof(WTS_SESSION_INFO));
        if (WTS_CONNECTSTATE_CLASS.WTSActive == si.State)
        {
            dwSessionId = si.SessionID;
            break;
        }

        current += dataSize;
    }

    WTSFreeMemory(pSessionInfo);

    bool bRet = WTSQueryUserToken(dwSessionId, out currentToken);
    if (bRet == false)
        return IntPtr.Zero;

    bRet = DuplicateTokenEx(currentToken, TOKEN_ASSIGN_PRIMARY | TOKEN_ALL_ACCESS, IntPtr.Zero, SECURITY_IMPERSONATION_LEVEL.SecurityImpersonation, TOKEN_TYPE.TokenPrimary, out primaryToken);
    if (bRet == false)
        return IntPtr.Zero;

    return primaryToken;
}
```

Comment: .NET programmers sooner or later always discover that writing an event handler for the AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException event is never really optional.  Without a debugger and the Holy Stack Trace, you're blind as a bat to discover the underlying problem.  And can never ask for help at a site like SO.

Comment: No improvement. I tried to listen to UnhandledExceptions events on both the Windows service and the exe, to no avail.

I guess I have to place it in the exe main (I did), but as I said, it never fires. It seems the exe gets killed by the OS as soon as it starts.

Comment: Could you show your code? Did you do all "magic" which described [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/winsdk/archive/2009/07/14/launching-an-interactive-process-from-windows-service-in-windows-vista-and-later.aspx)? May be it can be helpful. [Here is my code](http://pastebin.com/xhajdxrk) how I run some EXE under SessionId of some user. It's written in C++, but one can call it from C# via PInvoke. You can enumerate all session by [WTSEnumerateSessions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/aa383833%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just needed to change this:

```
si.lpDesktop = string.Empty;
```

To this:

```
si.lpDesktop = null;
```

...so the new process inherits its parent process desktop. Now it works flawlessly.